# Make google compute engine instance run Python 2.7.xx as 64-bit?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine

I am using python scripts to do calculations on Google Compute Engine.  Currently, each instance boots using Bash code which starts per the below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -yq install python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud
sudo pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
sudo pip install --upgrade google-auth-httplib2
```

I am having problems in that certain instances stop due to a `MemoryError`.  I have tried increasing the RAM available to the instances but this doesn't seem to fix the issue, so I am almost certain that the problem is related to the "4Gb" RAM limit with Python 32-bit rather than the physical amount of memory available.  On my laptop, I had the same issue and replaced my Python 2.7.xx installation with the 64-bit version and the issue is resolved.

As my Python scripts do not use any exotic packages or other libraries I thought I'd try running the GCE instances as "64-bit" versions of Python, but my problem is that I can't work out how to do it.  I appreciate that one solution might be to improve my program so that it doesn't need so much RAM in the first place but that is not really possible in my case.

When I SSH into an instance and run `Python -V` at the command line, it states `Python 2.7.13`.  Similarly, if I run the interpreter it states `Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22)` and isn't explicit about 32-bit/64-bit as it is in Windows.

Since Python seems to be installed/bundled by default on the Debian 9 images that my GCE instances are running, I can't work out how to "install" a 64-bit version on to the instance, or how to tell python to run that particular version for my scripts.  Google searches seem to have very limited help on installing 64-bit Python on GCE instances, which either means it's so obvious that my question is silly or there is something else that I am misunderstanding.  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Typing `uname -m` yields `x86_64`
Navigating to `/usr/bin/` and typing file `python2.7` yields a string containing:

```
python2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/
Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=6aac156c31a134f49fb9c5c62d223c163fb1b648, stripped
```

So presumably this means that my "hunch" was wrong and that the Python version that I am running really is already 64 bit as the operating system is 64-bit, and the memory limit is actually physical?

Comment: 1) Is your Linux distro 64-bit? Check with `uname -m`. Look for `x86_64`. 2) To check Python: `file <path_to_python_executable`. Look for ELF 64-bit in the output. 3) Check the size in Python: `import sys
is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32`

Comment: For Debian, 32-bit Distributions have 32-bit Python. 64-bit Distributions have 64-bit Python.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for your suggestions - I have put them in the question body.  The python lines that you commented yield "True" as well.  Thank you for the suggestions - I think I need to either revisit the way the calculations are done to see if there is a way to use less memory, or just accept that I need larger custom instances.  If you would like to post your suggestions as an answer I'd be happy to "accept" it.  Thank you so much once again!